# Command prompt staying open after drag'n'drop onto batch file

Tags: batch-file, vlc, multiple-monitors

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit (library folders moved to `E:`, system still on `C:`). I am using [someone's batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/87436/how-do-i-get-vlc-to-play-on-the-second-monitor-on-windows) to open VLC media player in full screen on my second display(left) and the control window on my primary display(right). The batch file is in my video library and I drag and drop a video file onto the batch file and everything is great EXCEPT the command prompt will not close until I close VLC.

I have tried `exit`, `cls`, `goto:eof` and `@echo off` at beginning in several different combinations with no success. How can I make the cmd window close after opening VLC or never show in the first place?

(please note that my cmd window takes up a majority of my primary screen because of how I use it for something completely unrelated, so no making it smaller and moving it won't work either.)

```
set vlcPath="C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"

%vlcPath% %1 --video-x=-1920 --video-y=1080 --width=300 --height=300 --fullscreen --no-video-title-show --no-embedded-video --no-qt-fs-controller
```

Comment: You can start it from a vbscript if you like while hidding the console !

Comment: can you specify or provide details?

Comment: Did you tried with the command Start ?
Check my answer !

Comment: @hackoo Please do not edit tags into a question just because you think another language might be more appropriate for solving the problem at hand. You can still propose a solution in that language as long as you clarify why you think that approach is superior to what the OP was originally asking.

Answer (score 2):

Try this batch :

```
@echo off
set vlcPath="C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"
start "" %vlcPath% %1 --video-x=-1920 --video-y=1080 --width=300 --height=300 --fullscreen --no-video-title-show --no-embedded-video --no-qt-fs-controller
Exit
```

And this what i mean to do it with a vbscript :

```
Option Explicit
Dim vlcPath,video,Command,ws
If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
    video = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
    vlcPath ="C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe"
    Command = DblQuote(vlcPath) & " " & DblQuote(video) &" --video-x=-1920 --video-y=1080 --width=300 --height=300 --fullscreen --no-video-title-show --no-embedded-video --no-qt-fs-controller"""
    'wscript.echo Command
    set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    ws.run Command,1,True
else
    wscript.echo "You must drag and drop any video over this script in order to open it in fullscreen"
end if
'*********************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'*********************************************************************************
```

Comment: Nice so in this case as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted !
See this ==> http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: You can try it with a vbscript too check my last edit ! and don't forget to accept it as answer !